# O знаках до и после закрывающей кавычки

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, переводы

Перевод:

> "Она спросила, проявляя интерес: «Что бы ты сказал, если бы узнал, что
>   это была я».

В оригинале стоит вопросительный знак в конце предложения. Переводчик ставит точку. Можно так? "Освобождает" ли переводчика глагол "спросила" от постановки правильного знака?

Вы произносили бы это предложение с восходящей интонацией?

Или это надо считать несущественной "оплошностью" переводчика?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Она спросила, проявляя интерес: «Что бы ты сказал, если бы узнал, что это
> была я».
>
> В оригинале стоит вопросительный знак в конце предложения. Переводчик
> ставит точку. Можно так?

Нет, это грубая ошибка. Вопросительный знак внутри прямой речи обязателен:
***«Что бы ты сказал, если бы узнал, что это была я?»*** Это вопросительное предложение, без вопросительного знака оно неправильно оформлено. Но ошибка эта - на совести редактора или корректора.

В конце предложения с прямой речью

> Освобождает" ли переводчика глагол "спросила" от постановки правильного
> знака?

Нет. Единственное исключение - точка перед закрывающей кавычкой не ставится.
Все остальные знаки, относящиеся к тексту внутри кавычек (прямой речи) сохраняются.

К сожалению, в нормативных источниках это правило изложено путано, постоянно возникают спору в отношении знака после кавычек, если прямая речь заканчивается на вопросительный или восклицательный знак. Я считаю, что это точка нужна, поскольку в правилах прямо не говорится иное. Ваш текст должен выглядеть так:

***Она спросила, проявляя интерес: «Что бы ты сказал, если бы узнал, что это
была я?».***

> Вы произносили бы это предложение с восходящей интонацией?

Все целиком? Нет. Только прямую речь. Но поскольку прямая речь идет в абсолютном конце фразы, то и вся интонация - вопросительная.

> Или это надо считать несущественной "оплошностью" переводчика?

Это ошибка корректора. Грубая.

Я думаю, что ошибка связана с ошибочном применением правила о непрямых вопросах типа *"Скажите, пожалуйста, который час?"* и *"Сообщите, будете ли завтра в офисе"*. При абсолютной грамматической тождественности этих фраз, первая обычно пишется с вопросительным знаком, тогда как вторая заканчивается точкой (или вопросительным знаком). Это зависит от того, как понимается первая часть предложения (просьба): как главная по смыслу или как вводное. Выбор - за автором.

Но к прямой речи и знакам внутри кавычек это в любом случае не имеет отношения.

Добавление.

О точке после вопросительного знака в кавычках.

> 4. Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит вопросительный/восклицательный знак, то после кавычек он не
>    повторяется: Читали ли вы роман «Что делать?»
>
> Неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются по условиям контекста,
> ставятся и после закрывающих кавычек:
>
> Я читаю роман А. И. Герцена «Кто виноват?».
>
> В каком стихотворении М. Ю. Лермонтова есть слова: «Люблю Отчизну я,
> но странною любовью!»?

Розенталь
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=178

Лопатин повторяет, § 159
http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg159.php

То есть точка нужна. Никаких изъятий из этого правила или специальных формулировок для прямой речи и/или "законченных" фраз внутри кавычек Розенталь не приводит.

Comment: большое спасибо всем за помощь! @Иванов 7-й: спасибо особенно Вам! Вы ответили на мои вопросы! : )

Comment: @Иванов Комментарий Лопатина к примеру с многоточием в цитате и без точки после кавычек: ... **цитата оформлена как самостоятельное предложение, имеющее свой собственный конечный знак** (многоточие), поэтому после закрывающей кавычки точки нет. Обобщение "_собственный конечный знак (многоточие)_" употреблено здесь в качестве аргумента, т. е. у автора нет сомнений по поводу других интонационных знаков, а точка, относящаяся к содержанию цитаты отдельно оговорена в другом месте. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137

Comment: P.S. В примере _Я читаю роман А. И. Герцена «Кто виноват?»._ нет прямой речи или цитаты; здесь название произведения - член простого повествовательного предложения.

Comment: @Anonym, стараюсь. ))))

Comment: @Alex_ander вы хоть бы номер параграфа приводили при таких отсылках. Там вообще вообше про цитаты говорится. "§ 143. Цитата, включенная в авторское предложение на правах его компонента..." и для такого предположения еще можно обсуждать, но и спорить можно (ибо Лопатин противоречит себе же). Но у нас-то вообще другой случай.

Comment: П. 4, на который вы опираетесь, относится к правилу "Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит опросительный/восклицательный знак (у Лопатина добавлено многоточие; минус пример с точкой), то после кавычек он не повторяется". Поэтому следующая за этим фраза о "неодинаковых" знаках после кавычек может относиться только к упомянутым в правиле знакам. Пример с "Герценом" верен, но иллюстрировать он может лишь случай, для которого действует оговорка "требуется по условиям контекста", что в рамках правила не раскрывается. Поэтому ваш вывод из правила не следует.

Comment: P.S. Вы не найдёте и в других главах у Розенталя (как и у Лопатина) ни одного примера, где при **оформлении прямой речи кавычками** (строго наш случай; "самостоятельное предложение") стояла точка после вопросительного/восклицательного знака и кавычек. Противоречий нет ни у Лопатина, ни у Розенталя. Помимо Лопатина и других двух источников, обратите внимание на учебник, который упоминает М_Г.

Comment: @Иванов7-й  Со ссылками нужно быть очень аккуратным. У Лопатина в пар.159, п.3 есть такой пример: «Вы читали романы «Что делать?» и «Кто виноват ?» Здесь или первые кавычки лишние, или их (вторых) в конце не хватает. По поводу ошибок-опечаток уже были вопросы на Форуме.

Answer (score 3):

Ввиду наличия кавычек фрагмент "Что бы ты сказал..." нельзя трактовать как элемент косвенной речи - в предложении *цитируется вопрос*. Поэтому вопросительный знак (перед закрытием кавычек) обязателен. Точка после кавычек не ставится, поскольку цитата здесь - самостоятельное вопросительное предложение.

Comment: Насчет точки, которая не ставится, - вы несколько погорячились. Прямого указания на это в правилах нет, а споры на этот счет - выражают в лучшем случае субъективное мнение.

Comment: Нет, не погорячился. О каких _спорах_ речь, я не в курсе. Насчёт того, что "в правилах нет". _В конце фразы после закрывающих цитату кавычек: ... в) **не** ставят никаких знаков, если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак, а заключенная в кавычки цитата является самостоятельным предложением..._
(А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова. Справочник издателя и автора. М., 2003)
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76

Comment: Споры о точке. Мильчин спорит с Лопатиным и "Правилами" образца 56 года. При этом Мильчин автор всего лишь рекомнедательного справочника для **издателей** и его мнение субъективно, хотя и растиражировано многими. А в **правилах** нет указания на что-то подобное.

Answer (score 2):

Это не оплошность переводчика, а трагический момент русской пунктуации.

Ваше предложение повествовательное, следовательно должно оканчиваться точкой. Но внутри этого повествовательного предложения есть прямая речь, представляющая собой вопросительное предложение, которое обязано оканчиваться вопросительным знаком.

Трагический момент заключается в том, что проблема сочетания знака вопроса (или восклицательного знака) внутри прямой речи с точкой после закрывающих кавычек не решена по сей день.

Приятное исключение - это когда интонация авторской речи совпадает с цитируемой; классический пример:

*Вы читали роман Чернышевского "Что делать?"*

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=178)**:

> Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит вопросительный/восклицательный
> знак, то после кавычек он не повторяется: Читали ли вы роман «Что
> делать?»
>
> Неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются по условиям контекста,
> ставятся и после закрывающих кавычек:
>
> Я читаю роман А. И. Герцена «Кто виноват?».
>
> В каком стихотворении М. Ю. Лермонтова есть слова: «Люблю Отчизну я,
> но странною любовью!»?

То есть по Розенталю Ваше предложение должно выглядеть так:

*Она спросила, проявляя интерес: «Что бы ты сказал, если бы узнал, что это была я?».* (Заодно неплохо бы избавиться от двух "бы": *Она спросила, проявляя интерес: «Что бы ты сказал, если **б** узнал, что это была я?».*)

Но это сочетание знаков народ не любит всей душою!

Однако **[вот ответ](http://yermolovich.ru/board/1-1-0-88)** современного нам российского лингвиста и переводчика, доктора филологических наук Дмитрия Ивановича Ермоловича:

> Вы задали далеко не праздный вопрос. Дело не в новой моде, а в
> некоторой нечёткости старых правил. Если руководствоваться
> справочником Д. Э. Розенталя по правописанию и стилистике, то там нет
> прямого и недвусмысленного указания на то, нужно ли ставить точку
> после закрывающих прямую речь кавычек, перед которыми стоит
> вопросительный или восклицательный знак. В §119 сказано следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что пока выбор знака остаётся делом вкуса переводчика или редактора.

Comment: Так или иначе, вопросительный знак внутри прямой речи обязателен, не так ли? Спорить можно лишь о постановке точки после закрывающей кавычки. Так что в любом случае надо призать: переводчик ошибся.

Comment: Именно так! )))

Comment: Из примеров Розенталя не следует вывод, что во _всех_ случаях вопр. знака перед закрытием кавычек после них в конце повествов. предложения нужна точка: в его примерах не вопрос цитируется, а приводится заголовок с вопр. знаком.

Comment: Не поняла про заголовок. Вот пример из Р. к "нашему" случаю: *Я читаю роман А. И. Герцена «Кто виноват?».* А, поняла; это и есть "заголовок". Тогда можно воспользоваться подробнейшим анализом Ермоловича.

Comment: Да, название книги имел в виду, оно пишется в кавычках не по причине цитирования. Источник правила насчёт точки я привёл в двух комментариях к другим ответам.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **Она спросила, проявляя интерес: «Что бы ты сказал, если бы узнал, что это была я?»**

[Розенталь. §119. Прямая речь после авторских слов](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/52.htm#%D0%B7_01:)

Перед прямой речью, следующей за авторскими словами, ставится двоеточие, причем первое слово прямой речи пишется с прописной буквы. **Вопросительный и восклицательный знаки, а также многоточие ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками, а точка после них.** Например: Наконец, я ей сказал: «Хочешь, пойдем прогуляться на вал?» (Лермонтов); Лежа на тюке и плача, он дергал руками и ногами и шептал: «Мама! Мама!» (Чехов); Закричали: «Двоих... Санитары... Гляди, гляди – еще летит... Лезь под вагоны...» (А.Н. Толстой); Хозяйка очень часто обращалась к Чичикову со словами: «Вы очень мало взяли» (Гоголь).

Примечание. В последнем предложении перенос точки: точка ставится после указание на автора, заключенное в скобки.

Comment: _Перенос точки_ откуда? Вы правильно не поставили точку в исходном предложении, но из приведённого правила это не следует, как не следует обратного из приведённых примеров - нет предложения, заканчивающегося цитатой с вопросом.

Comment: Хозяйка очень часто обращалась к Чичикову со словами: «Вы очень мало взяли».  Так правильно? Я про эту точку, которая у Розенталя стоит после указания автора (Гоголь).

Comment: Понял, вы имели в виду точку из содержания цитаты.

Answer (score 1):

Простое и понятное правило для школьников:

Вопросительный, восклицательный знаки и многоточие ставятся перед кавычками, точка - после кавычек.

**Схемы: А: «П!»     А: «П?»     А: «П...»     А: «П».**

[(Русский язык, 11 класс)](http://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/11-klass/predlozheniia-s-chuzhoi-rechiu-10913/znaki-prepinaniia-pri-priamoi-rechi-11046/re-49240124-a872-4636-a9bd-f0054a14c7e1)

Comment: Точка ставится после кавычек только если "ставится" (= если цитата - **не** самостоятельное предложение). Это есть напр. в справочнике для школьников же по ЕГЭ (более ранний источник этого же правила дословно цитирует "Грамота"):  Воскресенская Е.О. ЕГЭ. Русский язык: универсальный справочник. - М. Яуза-пресс, 2013, с. 247:
https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=lC9rAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA247&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=YMYE4VZJfQ&sig=ACfU3U14fkJFzbB28fy8BaJ42kX-wIsW_w&w=1280

Comment: @Alex_ander, По-моему, вы неточно сформулировали. Давайте уточним.Точка ставится после кавычек, если цитата - самостоятельное выражение, не требующее после себя восклицательного, вопросительного знака или многоточия. (А: "П".). Наряду с этим, после кавычек ставят точку, если цитата не является самостоятельным предложением, а выступает как часть придаточного (даже если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак).

Comment: Повторю пункт из правила, на которое я вчера сослался в другом комментарии: В конце фразы после закрывающих цитату кавычек: _... в) не ставят никаких знаков, если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак, а заключенная в кавычки цитата является самостоятельным предложением..._ (А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова. Справочник издателя и автора. М., 2003) http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76 Пример там с восклицательным знаком (другой частный случай): _Глава заканчивается словами: «Прощай, философия, прощай, молодость, прощай, Германия!»_

Comment: **P.S.** Видимо, всё-таки мы одинаково понимаем точку после кавычек: это точка из самостоятельного повествовательного предложения цитаты.