# Наличие/отсутствие точки в конце предложения с прямой речью после кавычек при наличии перед кавычками: "?", "!", "..."

Tags: пунктуация

На этом портале очень много раз поднимался данный вопрос. Лучшее обсуждение, как мне кажется, здесь: [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432477/o-знаках-до-и-после-закрывающей-кавычки/432480#432480](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432477/o-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8/432480#432480)
Однако точки в вопросе с точкой так и не было поставлено (да, каламбур). Кто-то говорит, что логично предложение закончить точкой (и я согласен), но везде встречаю лишь примеры, где предложение остается с кавычками на конце. Что-то изменилось за последние год-два? Какая-нибудь конкретика была внесена в этот вопрос? Вы сами как бы писали?
**Он подтолкнул меня в спину и шепнул: "вперед!".**
**Она сумела выдернуть меня из раздумий, коснувшись моей руки и спросив: "Так нужна я вам или нет?".**
И т.п.

Пресловутые примеры:
*Читали ли вы роман Чернышевского «Что делать?»*
*Драматический кружок готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!».*
И ссылки на Розенталя, и указания на то, что одинаковые знаки до и после кавычек не ставятся, − не нужны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Из вопроса Александра: *Он подтолкнул меня в спину и шепнул: "вперед!".*
Из ответа Александра: *Он подтолкнул меня в спину и шепнул: "вперед!"*

Оба предложения оформлены неверно. Правильно так (предложение в кавычках должно начинаться с заглавной буквы; точки после кавычек нет):
*Он подтолкнул меня в спину и шепнул: **"В**перед!"*

Примеры:
*Я предложил ему выпить, Костя решительно отказался ("Вообще не пью!") и шепнул мне на ухо: "Лукаса нашел!"* (Ю. Азаров. По следу); *Тогда Иван подкатил нарту, постелил оленьи шкуры и шепнул Марии: «Ложись и не шевелись!»* (В. Писигин. Письма с Чукотки).

•• Из вопроса: *Она сумела выдернуть меня из раздумий, коснувшись моей руки и спросив: "Так нужна я вам или нет?".*
Правильно без точки в конце.

Примеры:
*Так он и сделал, негромко спросив: "Почему, товарищ Фадеев, вы не хотите нам помочь?"* (Г. Фукс. Двое в барабане); *И тогда Адмирал — вот злопамятный человек! — попросил подвинуть к нему стоявшую на другом конце стола старинную рассохшуюся шкатулку, со злорадной усмешкой открыл ее, достал какую-то бумагу и протянул мне, спросив: «Вам знаком этот почерк?»* (В. Войнович. Монументальная пропаганда).

••• Для цитат и названий имеются свои правила, а для прямой речи — такие:

> **Вопросительный** и **восклицательный** знаки, а также многоточие ставятся *перед* закрывающими кавычками, а точка — *после* них.

Сказал [произнес, сообщил, подтвердил]: "Вперед".
Крикнул [cкомандовал, отрезал, заорал]: "Вперед!"
Спросил [удивился, изумился, обомлел]: "Вперед?"
Прошептал [простонал, прохрипел, пробормотал]: "Вперед..."

[Прямая речь после слов автора](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=156#pp156)

Answer (score 0):

Вы, по-видимому, путаете два принципиально разных случая: когда цитата является самостоятельным членом предложения и когда не является.

- Драматический кружок готовит к постановке пьесу «В бой!».
- Она сумела выдернуть меня из раздумий, коснувшись моей руки и
  спросив: "Так нужна я вам или нет?"

Эти два случая не тождественны. В первом фраза в кавычках — это определение, во втором — самостоятельное предложение. Фактически отличить их можно наличию двоеточия перед кавычками: если оно есть, то фраза в кавычках — самостоятельное предложение.

Точка в конце не ставится только в том случае, когда фраза в кавычках — самостоятельное предложение, завешающееся многоточием, вопросом или восклицательным знаком.

Что касается указанного вами ответа, а именно этой его части:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения], то я вижу тут формальный подход и попытку этот подход наречь "здравым смыслом" (тем самым априори нарекая другие мнения "нездравосмысленными").

Точка обозначает **понижение голоса** в конце предложения, а не просто то, что оно повествовательное. Произнесите фразу *«Она спросила меня: "Ты хочешь есть?"»* и послушайте: где здесь понижение голоса в конце? А теперь произнесите: *«Она меня спросила, хочу ли я есть»*. Вот вам и понижение голоса в конце.

Comment: Нет, ничего не путаю, специально указал, что пример с пьесой "В бой!" не интересует, так как в нем все понятно. Волнуют предложения с прямой речью, где в конце вопросительный, восклицательный знаки или многоточие – то, почему мы не закрываем все предложение точкой.

Comment: @Александр Понятно. На этот ваш вопрос я тоже постарался ответить: точка не нужна, поскольку нет понижения голоса, а финальный знак, завершающий предложение и показывающий движение голоса, уже есть. На мой взгляд, это не менее логично, чем подход филолога в процитированном ответе. Впрочем, и мой вариант не всеобъясняющ, потому что остаётся вопрос, почему в подобном случае ставится точка после скобок с восклицательным выражением, если голос не уходит вниз. ***Она спросила меня, хочу ли я есть (а я хотел!).***

Answer (score 0):

Примеры из Нацкорпуса показывают, что в подавляющем большинстве случаев предложения, заканчивающиеся вопросительным/восклицательным знаком с кавычками или многоточием с кавычками, дополнительно точкой не закрываются. Поэтому считаю такой вариант нормой.
Верно:
*Он подтолкнул меня в спину и шепнул: "вперед!"*
*Она сумела выдернуть меня из раздумий, коснувшись моей руки и спросив: "Так нужна я вам или нет?"*