# Точка после кавычек в прямой речи, если после неё абзац продолжается

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, прямая-речь, абзац

В прямой речи точка ставится после кавычки, все остальные знаки - внутри, и точка за кавычками уже не нужна. То есть /"Прямая речь"./, /"Прямая речь?"/.
Но как быть, если предложение заканчивается прямой речью, и это предложение — часть абзаца?

**Пример:**
*Ещё с прошлого его визита в голове застряла мысль: «Зачем вообще такому человеку кошка?». От Максима не исходило злобы или чего-то подобного, лишь безразличие, ясно показывающее, что кошатником он не был.*

Нужна ли в данном случае точка? Ведь здесь прямая речь не идёт сама по себе, она часть предложения, после которого абзац продолжается. Или это не имеет значения и точку нужно убрать?

Comment: Говорят, что при этом он воскликнул на латыни: «Такова участь тиранов!» В театре началась паника, и убийцу не смогли схватить.

Answer (score 2):

Если предложение заканчивается прямой речью (не цитатой!) с вопросительным знаком на конце, то после закрывающих кавычек **точка не ставится**. И для пунктуационного оформления нет никакой разницы, следует ли за этим предложением другой текст или нет.

*Ещё с прошлого его визита в голове застряла мысль: «Зачем вообще такому человеку кошка?» От Максима не исходило злобы...*

*А как свернули за угол, так вылетела целая толпа — парни, девушки, кто с надувными поясами, кто с мячами, и сразу к ней: «Лина, что с вами? Что **случилось?»** Окружили, подхватили за спину, посадили на скамейку* (Ю. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей).

Сегодня действуют такие правила. Жаркая дискуссия по этому поводу есть на нашем сайте: здесь имеются и ссылки (не буду их дублировать), и примеры, и мнения.
[O знаках до и после закрывающей кавычки](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432477/o-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8/432495#432495)

Вот отрывок (правда, с восклицательным знаком) из "Царь-рыбы" Виктора Астафьева.

> ...воздвиг досрочно Беломорканал и довольно с него трудовых подвигов, на что родитель ответствовал коротко и решительно: «Яйца курицу **не учат!»** И вскоре после моего отъезда из Сушкова подался-таки на руководящий пост.

Интересно (и странно), что в его же ["Двух рассказах"](https://znamlit.ru/publication.php?id=1326) (журнал «Знамя», 2001) точка в конце подобных конструкций имеется. Возможно, это новое веяние или единоличное решение корректора?

> Вечером, перед отправкой его на фронт, они целовались до жаркости за старой баржей, вытащенной на берег реки, и сквозь стиснутые губы Валя патриотически выдыхивала: “Ты бей их, бей **беспощадно!”.** А потом легла на песок и сказала, что она желает принадлежать только ему одному и готова на все.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, вы совершенно правы: это не имеет значения и ***точка не нужна.***

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Схема, соответствующая вашему примеру, вторая во втором столбце.

Answer (score 0):

Нужна ли точка после закрывающей кавычки в вашем случае? Конечно, не нужна. Есть правило: если текст, заключённый в кавычки, заканчивается вопросительным знаком, восклицательным знаком или многоточием, точка после закрывающей кавычки НЕ ставится.
http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/165-oszp# (**§ 200**)